# Best pratice when choosing between objects

Tags: oop, inheritance, polymorphism

So i am creating a program that collects alot of different data from the database and creats / updates several charts for the end user to see.

***Now at some level all of the data follows the same pattern:
Every data has a date attached to it this date is used to display the X Cordinate on the chart***

***Every data has a so called queue (which is simply a name***)**

Now what i have done so far is to create a super class (abstract class). My idea was to  create individual sub classes of this super class and allow them to have their own implementation and fields.

Now to my question some of these objects will be relativly small for example i have an object that only consists of three fields with getter and setter. Is best pratice to devide and conquere or have as few objects as possible?

The alternative to having small objects is that a larger object that in short are talking the same type of object but half of them has a field that the other half does not I.E why i wanted to split it into two objects to avoid having a field that will be null 50% of the times.

Here is an example of how my objects look:

**Example on subclass**

```
    class Callback : ContactQueue
{


public int completedCallbacks{get; set;}
    public int completed_within_timeframe{get; set;}
    public int answerPercentage { get; set; }
    public override String type {get; set;}
    public override DateTime period { get; set; }
    public Callback(String type,DateTime period)
    {
        this.type = type;
        this.period = period;
    }
    public override String toString()
    {
        return type;
    }
    public double percentageCompleted {
        get
        {
            return completed_within_timeframe / completedCallbacks * 100; // todo
        }
    }

}
```

I hope you can understand my question if not please leave a comment and i will respond as soon as possible

Comment: From where I see it, your initial approach is the best. Sure it may seem a bit overkill right now, but it's the more future-proof if objects ever have more properties for example. Using a big object with different properties filled or not depending on the real object it represents is not very object oriented.

Comment: @Bartdude Thats exactly what i thought but i wasnt sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on your system. If you want to have a storage for your fields then you can have one object with many getters/setters.

But I would recommend splitting them by behaviour. You might want to add methods to your objects and there will be differences in behaviour you'll want to have. And at this point if you had gone with the first way, you'll have to make a lot of checks inside these methods to correctly execute it. You need to separate objects to scale easier.

Comment: Right now it is only fields like 1 datetime 1 int and 1 string

Comment: By looking at your code, you're in the right direction. Also you might want to implement some of the methods in abstract class like `toString` and getters/setters of `type`. and if needed you'll override them. Not every time you create a subclass.